# Is there a way to get a resultset involving 2 columns joined to the same table in one query in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple messaging system, and I'd like to display both Received and Sent messages. The relevant tables/columns are laid out as follows, with extraneous information omitted:

```
User:

id | firstName | lastName 
-------------------------

Message:

id | fromid | toid | message
----------------------------
```

The query I'm running is:

```
SELECT message.id, `fromid`, `toid`, `sent`, `message`, message.email, `read`, user.id, `firstName`, `lastName`, `rank`   
FROM message LEFT JOIN `user` ON message.fromid = user.id OR message.toid = user.id  
WHERE `toid` = '$id' OR `fromid` = '$id'  
ORDER BY `read` DESC, `sent` DESC";
```

(And for sorting in my PHP script, I do:)

```
$received = array();  
$sent = array();

while ($dbRow = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    if ($dbRow['toid'] == $id) {
        $received[] = $dbRow;
    } else if ($dbRow['fromid'] == $id) {
        $sent[] = $dbRow;
    }
}
```

So what I want to do select the messages where either `toid` or `fromid` are equal to the user's id, then sort them accordingly (i.e., if the user's id is in the `toid` column, it was sent from other user to them, whereas if it's in the `fromid` column, the user had sent it to somebody else).

The query almost kind of works, except the `$sent[]` array contains duplicates: it lists each row twice, once displaying the user's name and the other displays the receiver's name. I can kind of see why, but I don't know what to do to fix it.

I don't know if I need to adjust my SQL query or my PHP script, so I've included both.

I know I could just break it up into two queries, but I'm trying to improve on my SQL and learn more about how JOINs work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do two joins - in other words, join the user table one for the "from" and another time for "to", something like this:

```
SELECT message.id, `fromid`, `toid`, `sent`, `message`, message.email, `read`, fromuser.*, touser.*
FROM message LEFT JOIN `user` fromuser ON message.fromid = user.id 
LEFT JOIN `user` touser ON message.toid = user.id  
WHERE `toid` = '$id' OR `fromid` = '$id'  
ORDER BY `read` DESC, `sent` DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `UNION`? Look at the MySQL spec to learn more.